# Post to WordPress with API (Python)

Tags: python, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to write python script that automatically posts a post. Here's the script code but it fails with the errors mentioned below.

```
import requests
import base64

wordpress_user = "test"
wordpress_password = "P8zJ xns7 OU1g p8iS jaVt fffU"
wordpress_credentials = wordpress_user + ":" + wordpress_password
wordpress_token = base64.b64encode(wordpress_credentials.encode())
#print(wordpress_token.decode('utf-8'))
wordpress_header = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + wordpress_token.decode('utf-8')}

def create_wordpress_post():
 api_url = 'https://<website.com>/wp-json/wp/v2/posts'
 data = {
 'title' : 'Example wordpress post',
 'status': 'publish',
 'slug' : 'example-post',
 'content': 'This is the content of the post'
 }

 response = requests.post(api_url, headers=wordpress_header, json=data)

 print(response.text)

create_wordpress_post()
```

Here's the error:

`"{"code":"rest_cannot_create","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create posts as this user.","data":{"status":401}}"`

NOTE: The `test` user has administrator privileges.

I have searched the whole internet for days with no answer/help.

Comment: Could it be that the Auth header is being stripped by the wordpress server? See this [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/310898) as well this [one](https://github.com/WP-API/node-wpapi/issues/349#issuecomment-566206560).

Comment: @Kakedis I have already tried this, still same error.

Comment: Did you get this resolved in the end?